# Acer Aspire 5750G temperature

Tags: linux, temperature, acer-aspire

I have been testing (CPU and graphics stress test) my computer and logged the temperature: [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bfDgQwxe) are the results.

I'm wondering if this is normal or should I do something with it?

These temperatures were measured for about 1 hour in 10sec intervals .

The computer is an Acer Aspire 5750G, i5-2410M, Intel graphics/nVidia GT 540M(disabled in BIOS)

Comment: And during normal use (i.e. not during stress testing) do you have any temperature problems?

Comment: No, normal temperature vary from 40 - 55

Comment: Then you do not have any problems, don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 5750-6866 (the "little brother" system to the 5750G) and I know that my normal temps are around 50 to 60C during normal operation.

If I understand this correctly, this is a log from stress testing.  It might be helpful to post additional log(s) during normal usage.

Remember, folk wisdom says that Acers run hot!

(edit): Those normal operation temps are completely normal, yeah.

Comment: Thanks, I heard that wisdom, after this test I believe it.
So I think that those temperatures are normal